# Calling a string method assigned to a dict value

Tags: python

How can I call a (string) method assigned to a dict value like this

```
dict = { True: ''.lower }
```

I tried

```
flip = True
print("A".dict[flip])
```

but then I get:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dict'
```

Comment: Pass the string value to the method, by calling that method: `dict[flip]("A")`. You want to store *unbound methods* however, e.g. `str.lower` instead of `''.lower`. The latter is already bound, to the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {True: lambda x: x.lower()}
flip = True
print(d[flip]('A'))
```

prints

```
a
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way without using lambda?

Comment: @NilsLindenberg: use `str.lower` to get the unbound string method.